# How do I open workbook programmatically as read-only?

Tags: excel, vba

This is how I can open an excel file in vbA:

```
Workbooks.Open(file-path)
```

is there a way to specify that it should be open as read-only? The files I am opening have a password on them, and I always get the dialog that it can only be open as read only.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=filepath, ReadOnly:=True
```

Or, [as pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389543/vba-how-do-i-open-workbook-programmatically-as-read-only#comment60139462_3389577), to keep a reference to the opened workbook:

```
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=filepath, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Comment: It is helpful to know that you should encapsulate the arguments in a parenthesis if you intend on storing the opened workbook in a variable using 'Set'.

Answer (score 15):

Check out the language reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195811(office.11).aspx

```
expression.Open(FileName, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly, Format, Password, WriteResPassword, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Origin, Delimiter, Editable, Notify, Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
```

Comment: Better response as it also makes it clear that *password* can be used on open.