# Insert excel file to excel using power query in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have one .xlsm file generated by SAP BeX Analyzer on sharedir, if i try to open the file and extract it to another workbook, I get error due to the fact, BeX is 32bit and I have 64bit Office. Therefore I went with powerquery, it works fine, but from time to time, it drops Runtime 1004 Expression.SyntaxError: Token Equal expected.

The problem happens when .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False is inititated.

I made some changes in the code - mostly variables.

My code:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add

wb.Queries.Add Name:="DF_GRID_1", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(" & Chr(34) & path & sfile & Chr(34) & "), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    DF_GRID_1_DefinedName = Source{[Item=""DF_GRID_1"",Kind=""DefinedName""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(DF_GRID_1_De" & _
    "finedName, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Sending System"", type text}, {""Organizational Unit"", type text}, {""Contract Number"", type text}, {""Contract Number Description"", type text}, {""Contract Start Date"", type date}, {""Contract position"", Int64.Type}, {""Material number ID"", type" & _
    " text}, {""Material Description"", type text}, {""Start date of accept"", type date}, {""Minimum contract ter"", Int64.Type}, {""End date of previous"", type text}, {""Blacklist ID"", type text}, {""Contract position st"", Int64.Type}, {""Contract position ty"", Int64.Type}, {""Portfolio ID"", Int64.Type}, {""Business Area"", Int64.Type}, {""Distribution channel"", " & _
    "Int64.Type}, {""Material group"", Int64.Type}, {""Condition Type"", Int64.Type}, {""Date From"", type date}, {""Price duration in mo"", Int64.Type}, {""Currency"", type text}, {""Months before min. c"", type text}, {""Amortization Period"", Int64.Type}, {""Selection period"", type date}, {""Sales Quantity of contract position"", Int64.Type}, {""Value per month"", ty" & _
    "pe number}, {""SSP Value"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=DF_GRID_1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [DF_GRID_1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "DF_GRID_1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False

I removed adding new sheet, make file and workbook variable, table from BeX (DF_GRID_1) remains.

The code when I record macro:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="DF_GRID_1", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""\\server\_Monthly closing\IFRS_CNTR_RAW_DATA.xlsm""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    DF_GRID_1_DefinedName = Source{[Item=""DF_GRID_1"",Kind=""DefinedName""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(DF_GRID_1_De" & _
    "finedName, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Sending System"", type text}, {""Organizational Unit"", type text}, {""Contract Number"", type text}, {""Contract Number Description"", type text}, {""Contract Start Date"", type date}, {""Contract position"", Int64.Type}, {""Material number ID"", type" & _
    " text}, {""Material Description"", type text}, {""Start date of accept"", type date}, {""Minimum contract ter"", Int64.Type}, {""End date of previous"", type text}, {""Blacklist ID"", type text}, {""Contract position st"", Int64.Type}, {""Contract position ty"", Int64.Type}, {""Portfolio ID"", Int64.Type}, {""Business Area"", Int64.Type}, {""Distribution channel"", " & _
    "Int64.Type}, {""Material group"", Int64.Type}, {""Condition Type"", Int64.Type}, {""Date From"", type date}, {""Price duration in mo"", Int64.Type}, {""Currency"", type text}, {""Months before min. c"", type text}, {""Amortization Period"", Int64.Type}, {""Selection period"", type date}, {""Sales Quantity of contract position"", Int64.Type}, {""Value per month"", ty" & _
    "pe number}, {""SSP Value"", type number}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=DF_GRID_1;Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [DF_GRID_1]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "DF_GRID_1"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Is there any way to find out whats gone wrong? power query shows same error as VBA. I don't need anything to modify from the file, I just need to load DF_GRID_1 to worksheet of opened workbook.

The file cannot be generated differently - it is RPA generated file used by other processes.
I cannot open the file with my 64bit office unless getting error message which cannot be suppressed by

```
With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .DisplayAlerts = False
   .EnableEvents = False
   .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Occam's razor works, opening the .xlsm in read-only mode was enough to suppress the BeX macros inside

```
Set wbs = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path & sfile, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Kudos to thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389577/17572067